# Least norm in convex set in Banach space

Tags: real-analysis

The following statement is true for Hilbert spaces $H$:

> Every closed convex set ${\cal C} \subset H$ has a unique element $x$ such that for any $y \in C$, we have $|x| \leq |y|$.

Is this statement still true for Banach spaces? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: $\mathcal C$ better be nonempty.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit too long for a comment. The question was answered by Jonas and Giuseppe. Let me add that a result sometimes called the *Day-James theorem* characterizes the spaces for which the statement in your question is true:

> For a normed space $X$ the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $X$ is [strictly convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space) and [reflexive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space) (in particular $X$ is complete).
> 2. Every non-empty closed convex set in $X$ has a unique point of minimal norm.

See the discussion after the proof of Corollary 5.1.19 on page 436 of Megginson's book [An introduction to Banach space theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=fD-GeCsqoqkC).

The space in Giuseppe's answer is not strictly convex and the ones in Jonas's answer are neither strictly convex nor reflexive.

The question [Distance minimizers in $L^1$ and $L^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/286223/49437) could also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 5):

Exercises 4 and 5 of Chapter 5 of Rudin's *Real and complex analysis* state:

> **4** Let $C$ be the space of all continuous function on $[0,1]$, with the supremum norm.  Let $M$ consist of all $f\in C$ for which $$\int_0^{1/2}f(t)\,dt-\int_{1/2}^1f(t)\,dt=1.$$  Prove that $M$ is a closed convex subset of $C$ which contains no element of minimal norm.
>
> **5** Let $M$ be the set of all $f\in L^1([0,1])$, relative to Lebesgue measure, such that $$\int_0^1f(t)\,dt=1.$$  Show that $M$ is a closed convex subset of $L^1([0,1])$ which contains infinitely many elements of minimal norm. (Compare this and Exercise 4 with Theorem 4.10.)

You can guess what Theorem 4.10 is.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no, in general. For a simple example consider the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the norm
$$\lVert (x, y)\rVert_{\infty}=\max(\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert).$$
Then consider the vertical segment $\{(x, y)\ :\ x=1,\ y\in[-1, 1]\}$.