# In a reflexive Banach space using the weakly compact unite ball to show minimal distance

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and $Y$ be a closed subspace of $X$.
Suppose the closed unit ball $B(0,1)=\{x\in X : \|x \| \leq 1 \}$ is weakly compact in $X$.
Show: given $x \in X$, there is a point in $Y$ of minimal distance to $x$.

EDIT: Attempt:

Using weakly compactness of the unit ball, we know that $X$ is reflexive.

Now I know that since $Y$ is convex and closed, it also weakly closed; so that I construct a minimizing sequence $(y_n)$ in $Y$ such that $\|x- y_n \|$ will converge to the minimal distance.

But I'm not sure how to show that $\|x- y_n \|$ will converge to the minimal distance.

I feel like I could somehow use lower semicontinuity to get a minimal distance. But then in this case, $Y$ has to be compact.

Also, I haven't used that $X$ is reflexive...

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: $Y$ is a subspace, right? It's definitely convex! Every convex combination is a linear combination.

Comment: RIGHT! How could I miss that? Thanks!

Comment: Does this help you get further with your attempt? $Y$ isn't (necessarily) compact, but it's boundedly compact.

Comment: Also, there's an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848660/projection-theorem-for-banach-spaces), which looks to be very much along the lines of your own attempt.

Comment: Wow! Yes! I think this might be it. I am going to have a closer look. But this link totally saves my day! Thanks!