# Can the infimum becomes minimum in the following definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $\mathscr{X} $ be a n.v.s., $M$ be a subspace of $\mathscr{X} $, we know that the definition of norm in $\mathscr{X} /M$ inherited by $\mathscr{X} $ is
$$\Vert x+M\Vert_0 =\inf_{y\in M}\Vert x-y\Vert .$$ Can the infimum becomes minimum in the definition? Or under a stronger assumption that $\mathscr{X} $ is a Banach space, or $M$ is closed, can the definition be strengthened to minimum? If not, what is the counterexample?

Comment: You'll need closedness to ensure the infimum is attained. A counterexample, is simple, take $x \in \overline{M} \setminus M$. If you have closedness then I think you're good by some convexity argument.

Comment: Thanks. So it is convenient for us to define the orthogonal decomposition in only an n.v.s. ,can we?

Comment: You need a Hilbert space to do projections.

Comment: If the infimum becomes minimum, we can always define the "orthogonal vector" of the subspace $M$ to be the vector which satisfies $\Vert x+M\Vert_0  =\Vert x\Vert $, and we can similarly directly define an "orthogonal decomposition" without the structure of Hilbert space.

Comment: You can have a look at this post and the questions linked there: [On the norm of a quotient of a Banach space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299735)